# Media query won't work

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a theme with a limited body width. Needed one full screen header element. So, i've set up 2 divs. One with 140% width and another one for actual header. As width changes, so does the height of the one containing header elements. So, I need the background div to change with it. But media query won't work for some reason.

Here is html

```
 <div id="topcontainer2">
 </div>    
 <div id="topcontainer"></div>
```

topcontainer is the div that has all the elements in it, and topcontainer2 is background div

css

```
#topcontainer {
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
min-height:56px;
background-color:#D8D8D8 !important;
border-bottom: 2px solid #BCBCBD;
z-index:22 !important;
color:black;
}

#topcontainer2 {
width:140%;
min-height:56px;
margin-left:-20%;
position:absolute;
overflow-x: hidden;
background-color:#D8D8D8 !important;
border-bottom: 2px solid #BCBCBD;
z-index:-1;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1012px) and (max-width:1278px;){
#topcontainer2 {
min-height:98px !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Open up your Dev Tools inside your browser and inspect the element the media queries attributes are assigned to. Can you see the Media Queries CSS in the Dev Tools Inspector?

Comment: If you are doing this `width:140%;`...you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I do `* {max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%}`

Comment: For some reason, can't see the media query assigned to element, but when i check source code- it's there. To other comments, body width is limited by media queries to 1200 px for 1280 resolution and so on. I tried a whole bunch of solutions, including one here, but mine turned out to be the only working one.

Comment: You shouldn't have a semi-colon here: `(max-width:1278px;){`

Comment: power of habit :) that's not it though